# Returned value of a promise

Tags: typescript, promise

I missed some of the concept of promises (in TS). I don't understand why the following code isn't print on the console the `data` parameter which is `222`.

```
const p : Promise<number> = 
    new Promise<number>(()=>{console.log(1); return 222;})
    .then((data)=>{
    console.log(data)
    return 43;
});
```

It's printng only `1` instead of `1` and then `222`. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A promise is an asynchronous operation,

```
const p : Promise<number> = 
    new Promise<number>((resolve, reject)=>{
      //do some operations here, and the desired output is ready, say result = 5;
      resolve(result)
      //or if you hit an error you can get the error obj, e and
      reject(e)
    });
```

You can execute a promise call now, and the result after execution will be available in `.then`

```
p()
.then((resolvedResult:number)=>console.log(resolvedResult),(rejectedError)=>console.log(rejectedError))
```

Answer (score 2):

A promise doesn't return a value, it resolves with a value :

```
new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(1);
    resolve(2);
}).then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve the promise:

```
const p : Promise<number> = 
new Promise<number>((resolve)=>{
    console.log(1); 
    resolve(222);}
)
.then(
    (data) =>{
    console.log(data);
    return 43;
 });
```

Comment: The `resolve` has a red underline. Doesn't compiled.

Comment: @J.Doe Arash missed out a parameter so I added it. The callback when you create a `Promise` takes two parameters: a function to resolve the `Promise` and one to reject it.